# How to set a group alert

Tags: designer-workflow, alert, task-list

I have created a task list in sharepoint and created groups for teams. I want to mark groups in the assigned to section instead of having individual users. Also , want to set alert alert for group if anything is changed. I dont want to use any third party tool.

Answer (score 1):

1. To enable groups for people picker in task list: 
   Go to "List Settings" find "Assigned To" column and change property "Allow selection of:" to "People and Groups"
2. To add groups to alerts:
   In UI you can add only AD groups and users, so if you want to make a group alert - add all users to AD group and set alert for it. Or you will need to create an SPAlert object using code and add logic to add users from SharePoint group to it.